# Json.net Serializer settings

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've below data in a DataTable and want to serialize it in JSON format.

[image]

What I'm getting is:

[image]

I want the data in "Roles" field to be separated by semi-colon (;).

What I want is:

[image]

I want each role in Roles field delimited by semi-colon to be an individual property. Went through the documentation but couldn't find any solution or setting for doing that: 
http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html

Is it possible to achieve this purpose using Json.Net. Thanks for any help!

Comment: you can get that via making roles's type to Array

Comment: @techloverr: can you please guide me or point me to some article on that? your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you will need to make your own inheritor of JsonWriter. Start with the source code for the JsonTextWriter found here:

https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextWriter.cs

You will notice in that file the presence of `WriteStartArray`. It would be nice if you could just inherit from JsonTextWriter and modify the start/stop array methods. However, I don't see how you would call that internal method to go into Array mode. Also, you can override the `WriteValueDelimiter` method to insert semicolons.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I gonna check if I can do something as you suggested. I appreciate your help.